# jquery image slide

Tags: jquery, slide

here is the test page

http://www.studioteknik.com/html/test-portfolio.html

I got no error, but no hover-slide effect...

any clue anyone ?

---

Update, molf have fix the problem, that was the absolute position that did the trick.. but, now, when the text show up, the link underneath is NOT CLIKABLE

---

the corrected page is here : http://www.studioteknik.com/html/test-portfolio3.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update your CSS, make sure `.image img` is positioned absolutely:

```
.image img {
    position: absolute; // added
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will make the slide work. The image will be displayed outside the surrounding `div`, though. To fix that, add an `overflow: hidden` property to `.image`:

```
.image {
    // ...
    overflow: hidden; // added
}
```

---

**Update:** given that in the solution above you end up with text *behind* the `.image div` (i.e. with non-clickable links), you'd better slide *that* rather than the image. Instead of the above, do the following:

```
.box {
    // ...
    overflow: hidden; // added
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
$('div.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".image").animate({top:'200px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
}, function() {
    $(this).find(".image").animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:500});
});
```

Note that the we are now tracking the `hover` event on the `div.box`, and slide down the `div.image`.

Comment: It was that simple... you made my day, thanks !... why without the absolute it dont work ?, any idea ?

Comment: The top property has no effect for elements that are not positioned absolutely or relatively. This is per the CSS specs.

Answer (score 0):

it works with

```
position:relative;
```

also but you need to change your JS to:

```
$('div.webpreview').hover(....);
```

as there is no div with class "image" in your page :)

For clickable link:

STYLE:

```
.webpreview  img {
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:100;//note this
}

.box .linkDiv{
       top:-300px;
       position:absolute;
       overflow:hidden;
       z-index:200;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.box').hover(
        function(){
             $('div.webpreview',$(this)).find("img").animate(
                      {top:'200px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
            $("div.linkDiv", $(this)).animate({top:'0px'},
                      {queue:false, duration:500});
        },

        function(){
            $('div.webpreview',$(this)).find("img").animate(
                         {top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
            $("div.linkDiv",$(this)).animate({top:'-300px'},
                         {queue:false, duration:500});
        }
        );
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
 <div class="linkDiv">
    <strong>Client :</strong> Sous le charme des Ã©rables<strong><br>
      Manda : </strong>Conception et rÃ©alisation<br>
      <strong>Adresse : <a href="http://www.souslecharme.ca/" 
           target="_blank">www.souslecharme.ca</a></strong>
</div>
  <div class="webpreview"><img src="test-portfolio_files/souslecharme.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Also you can do this with changing **z-index** of div containing link:

```
       $('div.box').hover(
        function(){
            $('div.webpreview',$(this)).find("img").animate(
                        {top:'200px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
            $("div.linkDiv", $(this)).css("z-index","200");
        },

        function(){
            $('div.webpreview',$(this)).find("img").animate(
                       {top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:1000});
            $("div.linkDiv", $(this)).css("z-index","50");
        });
```

Comment: it was a test to see if the word image was the proble (as a protected word not beening use in css), i am back to the image class !..

Comment: i am pretty sure your solution work great.. but molf figure out a solution with just swaping the trigger, wich is fine for me... i will ry you way, but i will keep it simple, thanks !